# Where is Python cert_util?

Tags: python, openssl

I am using SSLClient (https://github.com/OPEnSLab-OSU/SSLClient) in Arduino IDE and need to generate a trust anchors file with a custom rootca.
For this reason I cannot use the online conversion tool and have to do this myself.

I installed the prerequisites mentioned in the header of the script, but it is still missing a module and shows the following error message:

> ImportError: No module named 'cert_util'

A Google search for *"python cert_util"* gives me no usable results.
Where do I get this module?

Header of the pycert_bearssl.py

```
# Dependencies:
#   click - Install with 'sudo pip install click' (omit sudo on windows)
#   PyOpenSSL - See homepage: https://pyopenssl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/
#               Should just be a 'sudo pip install pyopenssl' command, HOWEVER
#               on Windows you probably need a precompiled binary version.  Try
#               installing with pip and if you see errors when running that
#               OpenSSL can't be found then try installing egenix's prebuilt
#               PyOpenSSL library and OpenSSL lib:
#                 http://www.egenix.com/products/python/pyOpenSSL/
#   certifi - Install with 'sudo pip install certifi' (omit sudo on windows)
import cert_util
import click
import certifi
from OpenSSL import crypto
```

Comment: `cert_util` is a module in `pycert_bearssl`, you can check it out [on GitHub](https://github.com/OPEnSLab-OSU/SSLClient/blob/master/tools/pycert_bearssl/cert_util.py)

Comment: Thanks! I am clearly not accustomed to my new laptop keyboard yet -shame-

Comment: @xavc: This is the correct answer.
I copied only the script from somewhere. The github repository contains a folder \tools.
I have a working certificates file now.